# how to implement partial derivative in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I have a very general question to NetLogo. How can I implement a partial derivative. It's gonna be a simple model of priorities of a citizen with the respect to transportation vehicle.

Comment: This really depends on what you're taking the derivative of. You can imagine that if a turtle was moving and you take the derivative of their position, you could simply just use the turtle's velocity which would be the positional displacement between two time units.

Comment: You would have to implement every rule I believe, I don't really know if there are already defined but I doubt it. Once you define every derivate rule, then you want to implement a method that derivates the given function using only one variable. Something like `parcial-derivate func x` where `func` and `x` could be strings or maybe a `breed`. It is a really broad question so you may want to narrow it down a bit.

Comment: Please add more context to your question. What are you trying to take a partial derivative of? How are you trying to use it? What have you tried so far?